# Solve the "Cheryl's birthday" puzzle using mathematica

Tags: puzzle

The "Cheryl's birthday" puzzle has been circulating around, the backstory is available [via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheryl's_Birthday). The puzzle itself is reproduced here:

> Albert and Bernard just became friends with Cheryl, and they want to
>   know when her birthday is. Cheryl gave them a list of 10 possible
>   dates:
>
> ```
>     May 15     May 16     May 19
>    June 17    June 18
>    July 14    July 16
>  August 14  August 15  August 17
> ```
>
> Cheryl then tells Albert and Bernard separately the month and the day
>   of the birthday respectively.
>
> Albert: I don't know when Cheryl's birthday is, but I know that
>   Bernard does not know too.
>
> Bernard: At first I don't know when Cheryl's birthday is, but I know
>   now.
>
> Albert: Then I also know when Cheryl's birthday is.
>
> So when is Cheryl's birthday?

An iterative iPython solution was posted here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/Cheryl.ipynb

I played around with it and posted my own procedural solution for mathematica here: https://gist.github.com/lburton/241a8083c5d764708010

Since I very seldom use the "math" part of mathematica, I'm really curious to learn how a more sophisticated user would approach the solution. I guess I'd award the answer to the most up-voted.

Of course I'm interested to know more about this general class of problem, so I can identify instances of it that appear in my real work :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a webpage I set up which solves Cheryl's Birthday-like problems in full generality (i.e. you can specify any set of possible dates) using Mathematica CDF.

http://cherylsbirthdaysolver.com

Comment: very very nice +1 of course :)

Answer (score 2):

The following is not particularly inspiring. However,

```
cand = {{"May", 15}, {"May", 16}, {"May", 19}, {"June", 17}, {"June", 
    18}, {"July", 14}, {"July", 16}, {"August", 14}, {"August", 
    15}, {"August", 17}};
c1[n_] := 
 With[{rem = Cases[Tally[n[[All, 2]]], {x_, _?(# == 1 &)} :> x]}, 
  DeleteCases[
   n, {Alternatives @@ (Cases[n, {_, Alternatives @@ rem}][[All, 
        1]]), _}]]
c2[n_] := 
 With[{rem = Cases[Tally[n[[All, 2]]], {x_, _?(# == 1 &)} :> x]}, 
  Cases[n, {_, Alternatives @@ rem}]]
c3[n_] := 
 With[{rem = Cases[Tally[n[[All, 1]]], {x_, _?(# == 1 &)} :> x]}, 
  Cases[n, {Alternatives @@ rem, _}]]
Composition[
  Row[{"Cheryl's Birthday is "}~Join~#, Spacer[2]] &, #[[1]] &, c3, c2,
   c1][cand]
```

- `cand` is candidate birthdays
- `c1` to `c3` are the clues from the three statements:(i) rule out months that have unique day (ii) rule out birthdays without unique days (iii) find remaining birthday which has unique month
- the rest is for "prettiness"

Run for answer, if not known.